# cannot find -llibSDL2main

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, sdl-2

I am trying to configure `eclipse c++` to use `SDL2.0.3`.

```
1) I downloaded  SDL
2)put `SDL2` folder with headers into `gcc\include` folder
3)I put libSDL2.a, libSDL2.dll.a, libSDL2.la, libSDL2_test.a,  libSDL2main.a into gcc\lib folder
4) I put SDL2.dll into my current project's configuration DEBUG folder
5) I added in `project->properties->c/c++ build->settings->mingw c++ linker->libraries libSDL2main and libSDL2 (pic.)
```

[image]

But it shows me an error that it `cannot find -llibSDL2main`.

P.S I had issue once with `winapifamily` but I resolved it by putting `winapifamily.h` in `gcc\include`

Comment: try `-lSDL2main`, the `-l` will add a `lib` as prefix, so you're linking `liblibSDL2main`

Comment: Indeed it helped. Thanks!